# Why does swift substring with range require a special type of Range

Tags: swift, string, substring

Consider this function to build a string of random characters:

```
func makeToken(length: Int) -> String {
    let chars: String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!?@#$%ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

    var result: String = ""
    for _ in 0..<length {
        let idx =  Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(chars.characters.count)))
        let idxEnd = idx + 1
        let range: Range = idx..<idxEnd
        let char = chars.substring(with: range)
        result += char
    }
    return result
}
```

This throws an error on the `substring` method:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Range<Int>' to expected argument
type 'Range<String.Index>' (aka 'Range<String.CharacterView.Index>')
```

I'm confused why I can't simply provide a `Range` with 2 integers, and why it's making me go the roundabout way of making a `Range<String.Index>`.

So I have to change the `Range` creation to this very over-complicated way:

```
let idx =  Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(chars.characters.count)))
let start = chars.index(chars.startIndex, offsetBy: idx)
let end = chars.index(chars.startIndex, offsetBy: idx + 1)
let range: Range = start..<end
```

Why isn't it good enough for Swift for me to simply create a range with 2 integers and the half-open range operator? (`..<`)

Quite the contrast to "swift", in javascript I can simply do `chars.substr(idx, 1)`

Comment: Because characters aren't that simple.  They don't all take the same amount of memory.  See the [Counting Characters](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html) section in the documentation for Strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift takes great care to provide a fully Unicode-compliant, type-safe, `String` abstraction.

Indexing a given `Character`, in an arbitrary Unicode string, is far from a trivial task. Each `Character` is a sequence of one or more Unicode *scalars* that (when combined) produce a single human-readable character. In particular, hiding all this complexity behind a simple `Int` based indexing scheme might result in the wrong performance mental model for programmers.

Having said that, you can always convert your string to a `Array<Character>` once for easy (and fast!) indexing. For instance:

```
let chars: String = "abcdefghijklmnop"
var charsArray = Array(chars.characters)
...
let resultingString = String(charsArray)
```

Comment: Why does Swift even need the complexity of accounting for scalar sequences? Why would I ever care about that? Personally I prefer the way javascript does it - it hides the scalar mess because I'll never need to touch it, nor will 99.9% of us

Comment: @inorganik They try *very* hard to be Unicode correct, future-proof, by default. Actually, Swift is the one hiding the scalar "mess" from us ;) To see what I mean, pls [check out this WWDC 2017 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/402/) around the 28:00 mark. They provide some nice examples of *why* this matters in practice...

Comment: Thanks Paulo I will check it out.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest converting your `String` to `[Character]` so that you can index it easily with `Int`:

```
func makeToken(length: Int) -> String {
    let chars = Array("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!?@#$%ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".characters)

    var result = ""
    for _ in 0..<length {
        let idx = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(chars.count)))
        result += String(chars[idx])
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: I think you missed the `.characters` I have at the end of the string literal.  In Swift 4, you will be able to drop the `.characters`.  I tested this in Xcode and on Linux before posting.

Comment: @inorganik BTW, using just `Array("abc")` will work fine in Swift 4 given the improved `String` class ;)